# MySQL slow to check if rows exist in large table

Tags: php, mysql

Currently I check to see if a user has viewed a video yet or not by checking if that user has recorded a view in our views table.

The query looks like this:

```
SELECT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM views WHERE videoid=:vid AND userid=:uid)
```

When displaying a page with video thumbnails, we overlayed "Seen", if the user has already watched this video, similar to the functionality on youtube.

The problem is that this query is rather slow to compute, as the views table has a large number of rows - 40 or 50ms. If a page has, say 60 video thumbnails displayed, there are 3 full seconds of SQL delay before the page can be rendered.

Is my problem architectural, or can I do something to speed the execution of the query up?

Comment: Does the `views` table have an index that covers videoid and userid?

Comment: CREATE TABLE `views` (
      `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      `videoid` int(11) NOT NULL,
      `ip` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
      `userid` int(11) NOT NULL,
      `when` datetime NOT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
    )

Comment: When you generate the page of thumb nails, do you get those videos also from the database? In that case you should in the same SELECT statement get the views information joined with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have an index on `views` that covers the videoid and userid columns, so the database is likely doing a full table scan. Adding the index should help. For example:

```
alter table views add index (videoid, userid);
```

Post the execution plan for your query if it's still slow.